# The installation process between root and user

Tags: linux, files, sudo, users, root

How does the installation process between "root" and "user" differentiate?

Some packages **recommend** you install them as root, is this because the access root has compared to a sudoer?

So when installing as root vs user, are the installation folders different or is it mainly the home dir? What if you install a package for another user, besides permissions, can the user use it as his own?

Is it more along the lines of: mkdir example; cd example and install?

Is there a difference where and how packages are installed via root and user? I.e. do files get put in the same folders, bin/sh, home dir?

Comment: Can you give some example of a package that you think "recommends installing as root" and give a quote of where it says that?

Comment: Nvidia -- Log in as the system user (root):

You'll need to connect to your server as root, either directly from the console or remotely using SSH.

Comment: Could you please add that to your question instead of as a comment.  Also, I don't think there's any reason to log in as root for installing it, it just sounds like Nvidia hasn't heard of sudo.

Answer (score 1):

> Some packages recommend you install them as root, is this because the access root has compared to a sudoer?

There's zero difference in installing a package under `root` or using `sudo`.

Comment: I thought that If root installs the package the owner is root, while if a user executes a command with sudo the user is still the owner. Is this incorrect?

Comment: That's not correct, anything that is run under `sudo` is *acutally* running under the root account.

Comment: So if a package was installed or a file created by user using "sudo" then the packages/files would be owned by root and not the user?

Comment: That's correct. Sudo stands for either "substitute user do" or "super user do".

Answer (score 0):

Some packages are installing dependencies in the root directory so you MUST install them as root.

But for the rest of the packages I don’t think there is a difference to install them as root or user.

From my experience I can tell that many times packages can’t be install cause I’m not installing them via sudo.

Also if you use the command:

```
$sudo -i
```

And then install them you may not be able to access them unless you type again `sudo -i`.

So the best think to do is:

```
$sudo apt install “package name”
```

So you can have acces when you type:

```
$sudo “package command”
```

And don’t have to type `sudo -i` first.

Comment: So when installing as root vs user, are the installation folders different or is it mainly the home dir? What if you install a package for another user, besides permissions, can the user use it as his own?

Comment: Some packages REQUIRE installation as root and for those who doesn’t it hasn’t any difference installing them as root or not you just have to be careful for the directory you install the file when u are root . If you put it in the root directory it cant be accessed from user even if the package doesn’t REQUIRE installation as root . And no root will have access to all the files so user can’t hide files from root HOPE I HELPED                           If yes plz mark my answer